# DateTime diff result when comparing number of days

Tags: php, datetime

I am trying to create a callback that counts the difference between old start DateTime and new start DateTime for a FullCalendar list of events.

What I am doing now :

```
 $event = AppointmentCustomEvent::where('id','=',$id)->first();
            $oldStartTime = new \DateTime($event->start_timestamp);
            $oldEndTime = new \DateTime($event->end_timestamp);

            $startDiff = $oldStartTime->diff($startTimestamp);
            $endDiff = $oldEndTime->diff($endTimestamp);
            var_dump($oldStartTime->format('Y-m-d') - $startTimestamp->format('Y-m-d'));
            var_dump($oldStartTime->format('Y-m-d'));
            var_dump($startTimestamp->format('Y-m-d'));
            var_dump($startDiff->d);
```

The var_dump is returning :

```
int(0)
string(10) "2017-04-27"
string(10) "2017-04-26"
int(0)
```

As you can see 27 - 26 is supposed to return 1 while it returns 0 which is correct so far, because I moved the event between two timestamps that are in the same day (from 27th at 14h to 26th at 18h) **while I need it to consider only days, without considering minutes and hours.**

Comment: Unfortunately until the difference hits 24 hours PHP is going to report back 0 days difference between the two. If you see that you will need to check if hours meets a minimum threshold for you to consider it one day (or to add an additional day if you will always round up to whole days).

Comment: @vv01f that is used to ensure you're in the correct namespace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on John Conde comment, **the first solution** is a turnaround that has been found to be like this :

```
$diffDays = abs((int)$oldStartTime->format('d') - (int)$startTimestamp->format('d'));
```

It tests if the hours are inside the same journey, and if it is the case, we add + 1 to difference of days.

**The second solution** is to simply create two new DateTime objects holding Y-m-d format of old and new Timestamps so that the comparison doesn't hold the hours difference.